# Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/(path to a text file 'data.txt'). URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request. (Microsoft Edge)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, microsoft-edge

Here is the `test.html` ,I wrote:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Home Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script src="test.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the `test.js`:

```
fetch("example/data.txt").then(response => {
    console.log(response.status);
    console.log(response.headers.get("Content-Type"));
});
```

Here is the error I saved from Microsoft Edge:

```
test.js:1 Fetch API cannot load file:///C:/Users/pp/Github/Javascript_Work/testing/example/data.txt. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.
(anonymous) @ test.js:1
test.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at test.js:1
(anonymous) @ test.js:1
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ test.js:1
```

Comment: Run a local server!

Answer (score 2):

you can't load local files for security reason. you should serve files on web server then you can make requests for them or you can use input type of file so the user can upload regarding file.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp


if you are interested in what's the security reason you can follow this link:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/201208/why-do-browsers-disallow-accessing-files-from-local-file-system-even-if-the-html

> If JavaScript in an HTML page could access the contents file system when opened on the file system, it could easily upload that data to a webserver. Then all an attacker needs to do is trick the user into opening an HTML document that was downloaded, and then they have your private data.